# How to see a livestream file with webrtc into html5 page

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, vlc

I need to embed a live video with url rtsp. I'm using webrtc, but I'm able to get just local camera live video. I'm streaming with vlc server several files, and I need to receive this video with rtsp live protocol due to network latency. How can I put it into html5 page using webrtc api?

Answer (score 1):

I think webRTC is not the technology you are looking for.

What you need is just to use a HTML5 video element to receive the streaming.  Take a look at https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player/wiki/HTML5-RTSP-Player

Comment: I've already tried about it, but I wasn't able to deal with it. I'd like to resolve with webrtc

Comment: That is not the use case for webRTC. It is possible but not easy, and I think it would be a bit overengineering. What you can do is to use a MediaServer, like https://www.kurento.org/, then insert the vlc stream into Kurento and, in the end, establishes a video call between your browser and Kurento.

Comment: I was giving a look at the resource you did provide but, it seems that it's not very well documentaed and is pretty much ambiguous in some parts.